# Installation failure - the mongodb driver for PHP on El Capitan

Tags: php, mongodb, driver, osx-elcapitan

I tried to install the mongodb driver for PHP on El Capitan. While running sudo pecl install mongo, I get the error message:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo

fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/evp.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [io_stream.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
PEAR Version: 1.9.4 PHP Version: 5.5.28
```

I tried mongo driver install with PHP 5.5.26 also.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-install-up-mongodb-and-php-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Article is for ubuntu, I'm facing problem on MAC El CAP. al though tried everything in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Install this script which installs a clean version of php:
`curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6`

See this blog post for more info: http://jacurtis.com/easily-install-mcrypt-php-mavericks-yosemite/

Comment: FWIW, I know the link says mavericks and yosemite, but I'm running el capitan as well, and it worked just fine.

Comment: It installed php but after that when I run this command pecl install mongo it gives me same error.

Comment: No need to run that command. It should be installed. Make sure you add extension=mongo.so to your php.ini and try printing phpinfo() from your app. Does it say mongo is installed?